# Display today's date in every cell in a single column in a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to display the current date in every cell in a single column in a google spreadsheet. `=today()` displays the current date in any cell, but I can't figure out how to make it work in an entire column.

I tried `=arrayformula(TODAY())`, but it only works in the cell it's in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some way of introducing a condition on each row, e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A),TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make an array operation - any, to make Arrayfromula works, so eg:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(row(A1:A),today(),))
```

will work

Comment: ups... @Tom Sharpe answers exacly the same at the same time :)